# Adding text elements to div with a background-image is causing white space to appear around the image

Tags: css, background-image

I have the following CSS:

```
body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#section-one{
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/738/200/300.jpg?hmac=x-GpfBAQrKyKnrXqne7UJ3rdVnkGD7e-uRhpCcZWb9I'); /*random image*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

If I apply that to an empty div as such:

```
<div id='section-one'>
</div>
```

The background image would take effect and there would be no white space around it(https://codepen.io/ob98/pen/JjXEMPK). However, when I try to add text to `#section-one`:

```
<div id='section-one'>
     <ul>
       <li>Item One</li>
       <li>Item Two</li>
       <li>Item Three</li>
     </ul>
     <div id="tagline">
       <h1>Text</h1>
       <h1>Text</h1>
     </div>
 </div>
```

White space appears above and to the right of the background image. This can be seen here: https://codepen.io/ob98/pen/MWyJOMd

If anyone knows what is causing this and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a margin of 16px wrapping your  tags.

Give the `<ul>` tag an `id` then overwrite the default classes by applying the css below.

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#section-one {
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/738/200/300.jpg?hmac=x-GpfBAQrKyKnrXqne7UJ3rdVnkGD7e-uRhpCcZWb9I');
  /*random image*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
}
ul#items {
  margin: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<div id='section-one'>
  <ul id='items'>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tagline">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't know ul came with a margin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#section-one` id.

```css
body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#section-one{
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/738/200/300.jpg?hmac=x-GpfBAQrKyKnrXqne7UJ3rdVnkGD7e-uRhpCcZWb9I'); /*random image*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```